# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts on working test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, failing-tests

I'm experiencing a wierd thing, I'm made a deployment on a refactoring of code on cases this monday (2019.12.02) and my test classes use the Test.setMock method. It worked so I started doing the same for accounts but, now I'm getting the 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts' error. When I tried to run case tests to look for distinctions set I got the same error as well. No changes made.

Do anyone knows if the winter 20 updtae changed something regarding API testing? I spent the day looking for some info on that with no sucess.

Comment: Not an answer at all, but be aware that testMethod has been superseded by @IsTest on methods.

Answer (score 2):

You must have an unmocked callout in code that is invoked by your Account and Case tests, directly or indirectly.

The most likely scenario based on your description is that some automation on Case invokes an update on Account - perhaps some type of roll-up functionality. Your refactoring of Account-related code introduced a new code path that executes on Account update which includes a callout at some point. This callout is then invoked indirectly by both Account and Case operations.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be the case that more than one callout is being triggered? If that's the case, here's a good start point
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html